# Having a problem with Proxy 504 error on angular PWA and Firebase hosting

Tags: angular, firebase, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA angular application hosted in Google firebase. 
Whenever the app tries to do any backend call it gives a 504 Gateway Timeout, with Source of Service Worker.

Did anyone have this problem with PWA + Google firebase hosting?

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: i'm also facing same problem.
Did you solve this?

Comment: I'm still seeing this